# Using Expression in lookup-method

Tags: java, spring

I want to override `keysForReload` method in spring xml to return empty Iterator

```
    <!-- MetricsMethodData Cache Store -->
<bean id="bean1"
    class="com.ext.Myclass"
    scope="singleton" lazy-init="true">     

    <lookup-method name="keysForReload" bean="metrics.keysForReload"/> 
    <!-- Not working as expecting Iterator while it returns ArrayList -->

      <!--  can I use expression language somehow value="#{metrics.keysForReload.iterator()}" -->

</bean>

<bean id="metrics.keysForReload" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list value-type="java.lang.String">                
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

this method I want to override in XML

```
   MyClass has keysForReload method 
    public Iterator<String> keysForReload(){
        return keys();
    }
```

can I use `Expression language` to get Iterator from `ArrayList`? because I can not change the method.

Example: `value="#{metrics.keysForReload.iterator()}"`

Comment: Yes you can invoke method in SpEL but you should define your bean metrics.

Comment: I have already defined bean `metrics.keysForReload` but the problem is lookup-method takes bean reference and Expression can used in values

Comment: seems it should be possible, what is the error you get?

Comment: @kuhajeyan can not cast ArrayList to Iterator!

Comment: should you really use @lookup?

Comment: because I want to override method to return empty iterator with changing class. Do you think is there any other way?

Comment: @amicngh suggested an approach not sure it would work on your scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke method in Spring expression language and assign to the value but in this case you have to define your bean **metrics**.  Look at this example. [SpEL example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/spel/spring-expression-language-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Should something like this work for you?

```
@Bean("keysForReload")
    public List<String> keysForReload() {
        return Lists.newArrayList("val");
    }    

@Component
public class Myclass{
//your iterator here
   @Value("#{keysForReload.iterator()}")
   private Iterator<String> itr;


}
```